# How to call a function from a seperate file and controller in angular js ? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, controller

For example I have my test.js which contains the controller testCtrl that has a funtion for example from below code. Can I access and use/call 
   that function which is get_data on my test2.js  which has controller test2Ctrl ?

```
#testCtrl (test.js)  
    me.get_data = function () {
            dataservice.service(me).then(function (response) {
                if (response.status == "200") {
                    me.records.questionaires = response.data


                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Put this function into service and that service you can inject into both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are properly included in the site, you could move get_data to an angularjs **service**. You can then [inject the service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) into each of the controllers and call it.

If the controllers' scopes are in a parent-child relationship, if parent defines *$scope.get_data*, the child controller can access it using $scope. You could define get_data inside *$rootScope* to achieve the same thing, just make sure it gets created before any controller calls it.